# How to implement behavior animation on property changes QML

Tags: qt, animation, properties, qml

I am trying to change `scale` property when I click on image, but I would like for it to change slowly. For now I have it instantly when I click on the image (the image gets bigger).
Here are my images:
[image]

Here I clicked on the first image and it is slightly bigger than the rest.
Here is my code:

```
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color:'black'

    XmlListModel {
        id: xmlModel
        source: "movies.xml"
        query: "/Movies/Movie"

        XmlRole { name: "id"; query: "id/string()" }
        XmlRole { name: "name"; query: "name/string()" }
        XmlRole { name: "year"; query: "year/number()" }
        XmlRole { name: "rating"; query: "rating/string()" }
        XmlRole { name: "path"; query: "path/string()" }
    }

   ScrollView{
       width:parent.width
       height: 400
       clip: true
    ListView {
        id:list
        spacing:20
        width: parent.width; height: parent.width*0.5
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        model: xmlModel
        clip:true
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        delegate:
            Rectangle{ id: rect; width: 300;height: 300; color:'gray'
            Image{
                id:id
                anchors.fill: parent
                source:path
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                scale:focus?1.2:1
                MouseArea{
                    id:area1
                    width:parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    anchors.fill:parent
                    Behavior on scale {
                                PropertyAnimation{ duration: 4000 }
                    }

                    onClicked: {
                        id.scale=1.2
                    }

                    //hoverEnabled: true

                    /*onEntered: {
                             // hobbit.scale=1.2
                              id.focus=true
                           }

                    onExited: {
                              // hobbit.scale=1
                               id.focus=false
                           }*/
                }
            }
```

So, in my code I have `Behavior on scale` part, but nothing changes. I tried different options and nothing. Any advice? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `Behavior` object outside the `MouseArea` object.

```
Image {
    id: img
    scale: focus ? 1.2 : 1

    Behavior on scale {
        PropertyAnimation{ duration: 4000 }
    }

    MouseArea {
        onClicked: {
            img.scale = 1.2
        }
    }
}
```